# A blindfolded player has 3 turns to identify 1 of 7 people in the room. How many possibilities?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to teach myself probability and the book I am using gives the answer $86737$. I thought it would be $\frac{7!}{(7-3)!}$ because the order shouldn't matter but we cannot select the same person twice. Thanks so much for your help, I have searched through the forums but just don't seem to grasp this very well.

Edit: original question exactly: In a party game a blindfolded player has $3$ turns to correctly identify one of the other $7$ people in the room. How many different possibilities are there for the resolution of the game?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Is the player picking the people with or without replacement? What do you mean by possibilities? Also, are you sure that the number 86737 is accurate? It has a strange prime factorization, and I think a typo might be possible.

Comment: The prime factorisation of $86737$ is $7 \times 12391$ so this is not a quotient of factorials.  I would guess that the problem is aiming at a subtraction.  Meanwhile $7^3= 343$ and $7!=5040$, which are much lower

Comment: @aras I just put the question in my main paragraph as it came in the book. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to clarify beyond that. I am just guessing that it is without replacement since we should be able to eliminate each person after being guessed. And possibilities mean the possible number of resolutions to the game. Thanks!